# Is it possible to select data named in numeric order in one simple line?

Tags: r, rstudio

So I've named about 19 series of data in numeric fashion.

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
data9
data10
data11
data12
data13
data14
data15
data16
data17
data18
data19
```

I'm needing to execute the same command for all of them and don't want to create a huge list. Is there some kind of trick to selecting them all in one line?

I know when working with regular numeric values you can group a large series with 1:19, but using data1:19 of course doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the objects in a `list`

```
lst1 <- mget(paste0('data', 1:19))
```

Or with `ls`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^data\\d+$'))
```